# Using imports with Nodejs doesn't recognize a default export

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using [`expo-server-sdk`](https://github.com/expo/expo-server-sdk-node), and I haven't had this issue with other packages yet, but I'm thinking that this isn't an issue specific to this package.

Basically, my IDE recognises that this package has a default export, and correctly autoimports it as,

```
import { Expo } from 'expo-server-sdk';
```

The problem is that this doesn't compile and throws the error,

```
SyntaxError: The requested module 'expo-server-sdk' does not provide an export named 'Expo'
```

I'm using the experimental ESM module loader with Node v13.13.0. When I initially set up the config and environment, I was able to use `import` instead of `require`, however I am supposed to append the extension of each file I import.

What can be wrong here?

[Expo post](https://forums.expo.io/t/running-into-the-error-the-requested-module-expo-server-sdk-does-not-provide-an-export-named-expo/37636) for reference

Answer (score 1):

If it's exported as default you only need

```
import Expo from 'expo-server-sdk';
```

instead of

```
import { Expo } from 'expo-server-sdk';
```

Comment: I tried that already, but it didn't work. Also, as per the [docs](https://github.com/expo/expo-server-sdk-node#usage), it should be imported as `import { Expo } from 'expo-server-sdk'`, so I misspoke, however [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61791786/2891356) is how I managed to get it to work, for now.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work around this by doing the following:

```
import Expo from 'expo-server-sdk';

...
let expo = Expo.Expo()
...
if (!Expo.Expo.isExpoPushToken(pushToken)) {
   ... 
}
...
```

Just `import Expo from 'expo-server-sdk';` did not work.